# get array of img with json into div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a [link](http://server06.amobee.com/aspx/nadav/test/json.html) that returns an array of images similar to the following one.

```
{ "imageUrl":"http://server06.amobee.com/aspx/nadav/test/banner320x50.png",               
"expandedImageUrl":"http://server06.amobee.com/aspx/nadav/test/banner320x320.jpg" }
```

My goal is to display the first image in a `<div>`, and when it gets clicked, it changes to the second image.

How can I achieve this using only HTML and JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain javascript, supposing you already have a div declared as `<div id=divId></div>` :

```
var images = {
    "imageUrl":"http://server06.amobee.com/aspx/nadav/test/banner320x50.png",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://server06.amobee.com/aspx/nadav/test/banner320x320.jpg"
};
var div = document.getElementById('divId');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', images.imageUrl);
div.appendChild(img);
img.onclick=function(){
   this.src=images.expandedImageUrl;
};
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/NFyFC/)

---

If you have an array of objects similar to the `images` object, you may loop to create them. It's less trivial than it might seem due to the "closure effect", that's why I include the code :

```
var images = [
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/crevettes-ail-courgettes-2-750.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/crevettes-ail-courgettes-750.jpg"},
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/cote-beuf-champis-02-850.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/cote-beuf-champis-05-850.jpg"},
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/onglet-truffes-850-02.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/onglet-truffes-850-05.jpg"}
];
var div = document.getElementById('divId');
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var image =images[i];
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', image.imageUrl);
    div.appendChild(img);
    (function(expandedImageUrl){ // we embed the expanded URL in a closure to avoid having the value at end of loop used 
        img.onclick=function(){
           this.src=expandedImageUrl;
        };
    })(image.expandedImageUrl);
}
```

​

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/qkaTz/)

---

**EDIT following question in comment :**

And here's a version allowing a click to toggle between the two images :

```
var images = [
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/crevettes-ail-courgettes-2-750.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/crevettes-ail-courgettes-750.jpg"},
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/cote-beuf-champis-02-850.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/cote-beuf-champis-05-850.jpg"},
    { "imageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/onglet-truffes-850-02.jpg",               
    "expandedImageUrl":"http://dystroy.org/re7210/img/onglet-truffes-850-05.jpg"}
];
var div = document.getElementById('divId');
for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var image =images[i];
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', image.imageUrl);
    img.setAttribute('othersrc', image.expandedImageUrl);
    img.setAttribute('width', '600px');
    div.appendChild(img);
    img.onclick=function(){
       var src = this.getAttribute('src');
       this.src = this.getAttribute('othersrc');
       this.setAttribute('othersrc', src);
    };
}
```

[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/ktZKn/)

Comment: thank you a lot but how to change it back to the previews image?

Comment: can i do it with fade out and fade in?

Comment: Yes, but 1) for this kind of manipulations I recommend the use of a library like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/). 2) Swapping images with fade in is often ugly.